# Bootstrap Responsive navbar not expanding?

Tags: html, css

For some reason when I go to a small enough size and the navbar changes to the dropdown one it will not expand no matter what. I cant figure it out.

Code: [link](https://github.com/Sphiinxx/SimplyEating)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please provide [the necessary code parts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) inside the question, not a link alone. When someone else sees this question in a few weeks/months, your linked code might have changed, making this question incomprehensible.

Comment: I did, that link contains the ENTIRE website....